# Can't add a New filter to Magento Magento's Total Ordered Report

Tags: magento-1.9, php, reports

I'm trying to add a new filter to Magento's Total Ordered Report (i.e. Reports > Sales > Orders from the admin panel).

The filter I want is *"Order Type"* and can be either *"Delivery"* or *"Collection"*

I was able to add the filter to the Report form by rewriting the *Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form_Order* class.

```
<?php
class Holy_Reports_Block_Sales_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form_Order extends Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form_Order
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $htmlIdPrefix = $form->getHtmlIdPrefix();
        /** @var Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset $fieldset */
        $fieldset = $this->getForm()->getElement('base_fieldset');

        if (is_object($fieldset) && $fieldset instanceof Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset) {

            $fieldset->addField('order_type', 'select', array(
                'name'       => 'order_type',
                'options'    => array("delivery"=>"Delivery", "collection"=>"Collection"),
                'label'      => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Order Type'),
            ));

        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

[image]

But when I run the report it does not filter the results by the *Order Type*.

I've tried to add the filter to the collection with `$this->_addCustomFilter($resourceCollection, $filterData->getData('order_type'));` by re-writing *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid*

```
<?php
class Holy_Reports_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        parent::_prepareCollection();

        $filterData = $this->getFilterData();

        $storeIds = $this->_getStoreIds();

//        $orderType = $filterData->getData('order_type');

        $resourceCollection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->getResourceCollectionName())
            ->setPeriod($filterData->getData('period_type'))
            ->setDateRange($filterData->getData('from', null), $filterData->getData('to', null))
            ->addStoreFilter($storeIds)
            ->setAggregatedColumns($this->_getAggregatedColumns());

//        $resourceCollection->$filterData->getData('order_type');
//        $resourceCollection->addFieldToFilter($filterData->getData('order_type'));
//        $this->_addOrderStatusFilter($resourceCollection, $filterData);
//        parent::getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('fulfillment_store_id', $filterData->getData('order_type'));
//        $this->_addCustomFilter($resourceCollection, $filterData);
        $this->_addCustomFilter($resourceCollection, $filterData->getData('order_type'));


        $this->getCollection()->setColumnGroupBy($this->_columnGroupBy);
        $this->getCollection()->setResourceCollection($resourceCollection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

I'm using xDebug and can see that my class re-writes are working, it seems to be that my PHP logic is wrong.

Comment: Add this `var_dump($this->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString());` and check the SQL query it's trying to execute

Comment: @Mayers, where should I put that `var_dump`?  I tried it in my _Holy_Reports_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid_  but I get this error `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Reports_Model_Grouped_Collection::getSelect()`